# How to nest Handlebars JS?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am getting a frustrating error because of my Handlebars JS templates.

```
Error: Parse error on line 9:
...      {{/each}}    {{/if}}
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF'
```

Handlebars in question:

```
{{if showSingle}}
    {{#with single}}
        {{> postSingle}}
    {{/with}}
{{else}}
   {{#each posts}}
        {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Is nesting like this not possible?

Just to put things in context, this was working fine:

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{> postItem}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the `#` from the first `if`:

```
{{#if showSingle}}
    {{#with single}}
        {{> postSingle}}
    {{/with}}
{{else}}
   {{#each posts}}
        {{> postItem}}
   {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```